# How to use multiple wxPython project files in one program?

Tags: python, file, wxpython

I am trying to make a pretty big app with many different parts and windows. I decided that it would look a lot cleaner if I had some windows have their own file and then import them into the main file. I tried to do this but when I try to run the class, it gives the error of needing three arguments. I do not understand how I should go about doing this so any help will be greatly appreciated!
Main file:

```
import wx
import Login
Login.apples(self,parent,id)
class oranges(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,"Mail",size=(700,700))
        self.frame=wx.Panel(self)
if __name__=="__main__":
    app=wx.App(False)
    window=oranges(parent=None, id=-1)
    window.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I get a NameError: name "self" is not defined.

```
import wx
class apples(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,"Login to Mail",size=(400,400))
        self.frame=wx.Frame(self)



if __name__=="__main__":
    app=wx.App(False)
    window=apples(parent=None, id=-1)
    window.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import wx
import Login
#Login.apples(self,parent,id) #this line wont work ... there is no self here...
#see below in the if __name__ == "__main__" part
class oranges(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,"Mail",size=(700,700))
        self.frame=wx.Panel(self)
if __name__=="__main__":
    app=wx.App(False)

    window=oranges(parent=None, id=-1)
    other_window = Login.apples(parent=None,id=-1)
    window.Show()
    other_window.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: The Login window never opens. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok thanks it works now except the window shows up in gray inside of white and I can't do add a button or anything.

Comment: Im guessing thats maybe cause of this line or something `self.frame=wx.Frame(self)` ... maybe try `self.panel=wx.Panel(self)` as frame is a funny choice for that ..

Comment: I have one last quick question, is this the best way to have one window pop up after one has completed its process?

Comment: I have the one window for logging in and when the login is complete , I want the main window to show up.

Comment: your login window should probably be a wx.Dialog that is shown modally ... and it should appear on top of your other frame ... or better yet just have a login space in the main frame ... I dislike popups in general

Comment: An example of a login frame and a main frame http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26602008/wxpython-show-dialog-on-main-frame-startup/26616375#26616375

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you included `self` as an argument in your call to `Login.apples()`.  The first argument in a class method (usually called `self`) should not be included in function calls (only function definitions), and is treated implicitly in Python.  It is used to handle references within the class methods to the class itself (or other class attributes/functions).  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained) for information on `self`

However, once you fix this, your code will still not run with the same error because you given no value to `parent` or `id`.  You will need to provide values for these variables before asking python to call a function with them

Comment: So what should I put in the parameters then to make it run?

Comment: Whatever values you want them to have.